# VB.NET - Open forms in TabControl

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a split container on my form. On the right panel of the split container I will open forms. I wish that these forms would be open within tab control, so that I could have them opened all at once (in tabs). Is this possible, taking in count that the order of opening forms won't be always the same – or in other words: First opened form should open in Tab page 1, second one in Tab page 2 etc.?

Comment: ***Please PLEASE*** post what you have tried, currently it seems nothing. We are not a coding service we help with specific issue's and or problems. Please, update this question in regards as to what you have tried and where you are stuck at. Otherwise I am afraid this questions may be closed.

Comment: Why do you need to put a perfectly good container inside another container?

Comment: @Plutonix. First I need split container to have left panel for treeview control. Second, I need right panel for opening all forms that I have. When one form is allready opened, and I open another one It is not seen - Its opened beneath first one, and you can't see it. So I need a tab control, to have opened multiple forms at once, in right panel of split container, and to be able to scroll between them plus be awared which ones are opened.

Comment: @Zaggler, nothing to post to show yet, just a designing issues for now, almost no coding yet.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 `I wish that these forms would be open within tab control, so that I could have them opened all at once (in tabs). Is this possible`, to answer your question, **yes** it is possible.

Comment: Ok, so It is possible. And how should I open them in tab control? As I said, I can't code them to open in specific Tab page, contrary -  Tabs have to open in order and show form that I clicked to open. And Tab control will be set as Visible False, so Tab page will be seen only when user clicks to open some form....I know, confusing, I hope you understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms are controls and you can easily add them to other controls:

```
Dim page = New TabPage()

page.Controls.Add(new Form With { .TopMost = false, .TopLevel = false, .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill })

TabControlX.TabPages.Add(page)
```

Ideally you should refactor and move the content of the form into a UserControl and then apply the control to both the form and the tabs, but changing few properties on the form you can achieve the same result.

Comment: Hi Uno, thanks for reply. Sorry, I'm VB.Net beginner, and I can't figure how to help with your code. I have added Tabcontrol on split container, and tried your code, but all It does is that it adds new page to Tabcontrol, no visible content inside this tab page though. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hi @LuckyLuke82, my example is with an empty example form. You may want to replace it with your ones settings the properties I suggested (assuming you already have the form objects). If you don't have the forms yes, assign the "new Form With {[...]}" to a variable, add everything you want and then pass it to the add function. Hope this helps.

Comment: After creating a new form f1 with the properties mentioned above, and you have added it to the TabPage, you must then use f1.Show()